# touch() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given

Tags: php, filesystems

This problem only happens the first time its called.
Second time, no error, no problem.
Called once daily to update currency rates.

```
private function updateRates()
    {
        $szContent = file_get_contents(self::OPT_URL);

        if(!$szContent)
        {
            throw new Exception('XML resource unavailable.');
        }

        $pXML = new SimpleXMLElement($szContent);
        $aRates = array();

        foreach($pXML->Cube->Cube->Cube as $pChildren)
        {
            $aRates[(string) $pChildren['currency']] = (float) $pChildren['rate'];
        }

        $pFile = fopen(self::OPT_FILE, 'w+');
        fwrite($pFile, json_encode($aRates));
        fclose($pFile);
        touch($pFile);

    }
```

Comment: touch(self::OPT_FILE), not touch($pFile)

Comment: What for do you call touch after modifying file? It is sensless.

Comment: @Mark Baker  Why not post your excellent comment as answer?

Comment: **touch is not needed here**

Comment: @Bogdan - Not worth posting as an answer for the reason you've cited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`touch` expects a file name, imo. You are giving it the file handle `$pFile`.

Change `touch($pFile);` to `touch(self::OPT_FILE);` and see it that works.

Comment: ok will change it, and see what happens.
A btw, it does not throw the error on all servers for some reason, all the same level of error reporting, but on some no problems.
Will report back tomorrow.

Comment: Ok that seems to work, so thanks. I'm giving the aswer to Pushpen, cos he was first, but thanks as well to Iserni

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `touch()` at all. `touch()` will create the file if it does not exist (but it exists, for you just created it) or it will set the time at the current date and time (and this was already done by `fclose()`).

Either way, you do something that has been already done.

That said, the correct answer is the one by Mark Baker: you need to give `touch()` a file name, not a file handle.

**UPDATE**: You ask, "Second time, no error, no problem - why?". I do not see how you could call that call and *not* get an error. Even if the `fopen` failed and returned `false`, you would get an error from `touch()`. So I fear that this "second time" either the function **does really not get called at all**, or there is **some subtle bug preventing its execution from reaching touch()**. It is also possible that an error *is* raised, but it gets catched or hidden somehow.

But this I know for sure: `touch(<resource>)` **will** fail each and every time.

Comment: ok that makes sense too, i will change it just to see if it works, but when(if) it does, i will then comment it out.
UPDATE Occurs to me, the second time, it will not be being called, as the file is already "up to date" ie it has todays date, so nothing needs to be done.

Comment: That's well. I was fearing some subtle bug preventing the second call from being issued - as they say, "behind every small problem there is a bigger problem waiting to come out". If you did it yourself to avoid unnecessary traffic, that's cool.

Comment: i've accepted the answer above, but thanks to you to. I will now also remove the touch from there.